# Scipy.misc.imread and io.imread are giving me different results. Why?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to run my neural network on my own handwriting. To read in the image I've used `scipy.misc.imread`, however I got a `DeprecationWarning: 'imread' is deprecated!`

So I tried using `io.imread` from `skimage` but it's giving me vastly different answers. What is the difference about these 2 methods?

Version1:

```
# I read in the file
img_array = scipy.misc.imread('/Users/usr/Desktop/NN/Test_Sets/handwritten/IMG_5.png', flatten=True)

# reshape from 28x28 to list of 784 values
# subtract array values from 255.0
img_data  = 255.0 - img_array.reshape(784)

# then scale data to range from 0.01 to 1.0
img_data = (img_data / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
print("min = ", np.min(img_data))
print("max = ", np.max(img_data))

# plot image
plt.imshow(img_data.reshape(28,28), cmap='Greys', interpolation='None')

# query the network
outputs = n_final.request(img_data)
print (outputs)

# the index of the highest value corresponds to the label
label = np.argmax(outputs)
print("network says ", label)
```

[image]

Version2:

```
import skimage
from skimage import transform,io

# I read in the file
img_array = io.imread('/Users/usr/Desktop/NN/Training_Sets/handwritten/IMG_5.png', as_grey=True)
small_grey = transform.resize(img_array, (28,28), mode='symmetric', preserve_range=True) 

# reshape from 28x28 to list of 784 values
reshape_img = small_grey.reshape(1, 784)
img_data  = 255.0 - reshape_img

# then scale data to range from 0.01 to 1.0
img_data = (img_data / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
print("min = ", np.min(img_data))
print("max = ", np.max(img_data))

# plot image
plt.imshow(img_data.reshape(28,28), cmap='Greys', interpolation='None')

# query the network
outputs = n_final.request(img_data)
print (outputs)

# the index of the highest value corresponds to the label
label = np.argmax(outputs)
print("network says ", label)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the incoming data has range (0, 255)?  Depending on the I/O library used, you may also be getting a float array in (0, 1).  To make your values consistent, always apply `img_as_float` or `img_as_ubyte` to your image before further processing.

Comment: thanks for  `img_array = io.imread('/Users/usr/Desktop/NN/Training_Sets/handwritten/IMG_5.png', as_grey=True)
small_grey = transform.resize(img_array, (28,28), mode='symmetric', preserve_range=True) 
`